# Error:405 Method Not Allowed (POST) when trying to save/upload media files to my cpanel server

Tags: django, file, django-views, cpanel, shared-hosting

I keep getting HTTP ERROR 405 when trying to save/upload an image or file to my media directory located in the app root directory on Cpanel. When I checked the error log I got:

```
App 8077 output: [ pid=8077, time=2020-09-02 21:24:43,037 ]: Method Not Allowed (POST): /accounts/profile/
App 8077 output: [ pid=8077, time=2020-09-02 21:24:43,038 ]: Method Not Allowed: /accounts/profile/
```

Everything works locally, but I don't get why the error appears now I hosted the site on Cpanel shared hosting.

in my settings.py I have

```
# ALLOWED_HOST = ['mysubdomain']
DEBUG = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT ='/path/to/subdomain/staticfiles'

MEDIA_URL='/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT='/path/to/subdomain/media'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

in my project-level urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in my app-level urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('signup/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='signup'),
   path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

in my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # Columns for Profile Model
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Image", upload_to=user_directory_path, default='default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        #  Return the username on the database "e.g Anderson Dean Profile"
        return "{} {} Profile".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)

    # Saves a users profile
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        img = Image.open(self.image)

        if img.mode != 'RGB':
            img = img.convert('RGB')

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            fh = storage.open(self.image.name, "w")
            ext = 'jpeg'
            format = 'JPEG' if ext.lower() == 'jpg' else ext.upper()
            img.save(fh, format)
            fh.close()
```

in my forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
            ......................
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
            ......................
```

On a similar issue I read, the problem was due to the POST method not defined in the views, but I specified the request method in my view.py

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login'))
def profile(request):
    # If this is a POST request then process the Form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #  Gets the current logged in user's data
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        # Check if the forms are valid
        if u_form.is_valid and p_form.is_valid():
            # Save the forms
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            sweetify.success(request, title='Account Updated', text='Your account has been updated!', icon='success', button='Ok', timer=3000)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        # If this is a GET (or any other method) create the default form.
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
            'u_form': u_form,
            'p_form': p_form
    }

    return render(request, 'profile.html', context)
```

here the GET method works, and my image loads, I can view the image via `subdomain/media/default.jpg`.

then in my .html

```
<form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ u_form|crispy }}
    {{ p_form|crispy }}
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="border-radius: 24px;" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> Save</button>
</div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Once I click the save button I get the error.
I also tried to force POST GET and even PUT method in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
# Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|PUT) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't really know what the issue is, is there anything I am missing here? Any help is appreciated
Thanks.

Still yet to find a solution to this. It works locally `127.0.0.1` It works when hosted on Heroku, but somehow when hosted on cpanel, once there is a file upload with the views it either gives an error 405 or error 404 for another URL that has to do with file upload also.

Comment: show us your defined url for this path in urlconf

Comment: I have added the url path

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work.

So I cleared all the files within the subdomain directory,

then I deleted the app and created it again, having only public, tmp, and passwenger_wsgi.py in the directory.

I then used FTP FileZilla to properly transfer my files and folders to the subdomain directory.

Then I followed every instruction here https://smartlazycoding.com/django-tutorial/deploy-a-django-website-to-a2-hosting

Also I saved staticfiles and media file in the public folder in the subdomain directory

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
# The absolute path to the directory where collectstatic will collect static files for deployment.
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/subdomain/public/staticfiles'
# The URL to use when referring to static files (where they will be served from)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'static')
]
# Media directory
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/username/subdomain/public/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then I ran `python manage.py collectstatic`

It works now.